# Angular CDK Overlay bring overlay to the front with multiple overlays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 15, and for some reason when I place a click event within a mousedown event, the click event doesn't fire. If I don't change the position of the element, (using `appendChild`), both the mousedown and click work.

Here is a minimal [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qzbpsg?file=src%2Fmain.ts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div (mousedown)="mousedown()">
      <div (click)="inner()">
        Inner
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef) {}
  mousedown() {
    const parent = this.el.nativeElement.parentElement as HTMLElement;
    parent.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement);
    console.log('mousedown');
  }
  inner() {
    console.log('click');
  }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish, is taking a Material `cdk/overlay` bringing it to the front when the overlay is clicked, as the user can open 2+ overlays and they can sit atop of one another. What I am trying to do is when they click on an overlay it brings it to the front in the `.cdk-overlay-container` (aka it becomes the first element in the container).

Is there a better way to do this, or a way to make what I have work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the "z-index" of the all `.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper`

Create a function toTop

```
  toTop(el:any)
  {
    document.querySelectorAll(".cdk-global-overlay-wrapper").forEach((x:any)=>{
      x.style.zIndex=x.contains(el)?1000:900
    })
  }
```

Then you can, e.g. if you're open a template

```
  <!--see that you pass the template reference variable "content"-->
  <ng-template #tpl let-close="close" let-data>
    <div #content (click)="toTop(content)"...  >
          ...
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vauceh?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)